# New Top Bar: List all sites with any rep

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

In the new top bar, could all sites in which we have any rep be listed instead of just those with a rep of 150 or more? Or is it the top 7? I can't tell.

Comment: How is it now ?

Comment: Edited to guess at "how it is now".

Comment: I have 6 sites listed (excluding careers), lowest with a rep of 116, the first unlisted is at 113.

Comment: Your avatar. I don't even.

Comment: It lists your top 5-7 sites by reputation. (I'm not sure what the specific number is right now, but I think it's 5)

Comment: Or better yet, have all sites on which we have an account listed before all sites on which we don’t (with a separator between them).

Comment: There are a *lot* of sites where I have a rep of 101.

Comment: Good point TRiG. Ton 10 maybe?

Comment: Cole:  My avatar shows something I actually do with too much regularity to locate noisy fans.